# Nginx bind fails when more specific IP using same port

Tags: nginx

My nginx config version1 looks like :

```
 listen 80;
 ...
}
```

And then I change my config to version2 like :

```
 listen 1.2.3.4:80;
 ...
}
```

And run `nginx -s reload`, reload fails with message `nginx: [emerg] bind() to 1.2.3.4:80 failed (98: Address already in use)` 
And if I first apply version2 config first, then apply version1 config reload fails with message `nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)`

Looks like nginx reload does not release the earlier binding before creating the new ones, causing the conflict? Can someone explain if this is the normal behavior, or it can be overwritten in some way.

My nginx config changes very frequently, and I don't want to do a nginx stop/start every time I make a config change.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like nginx is trying to auto assign the address, try to bind the address with port in the listen [directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen).

```
listen 1.2.3.4:80 bind;
```

Comment: even afetr using bind I get the error `"bind() to 1.2.3.4:80 failed", "errorDetail": "98- Address already in use", "operationName": "Default", "category": "Default"}`

Comment: In many cases the issue get resolved by stop and restarting the process by following 2 commands - `sudo fuser -k 80/tcp`

`service nginx start` . If this works which means it relases the address when you restart. Since you do not want to stop start repeatedly you can write a script with these commands and set the script to run whenever there is a config change.